# Running virtual box is causing a restart of the host system?

Tags: virtualbox, ns2

I am trying to use ns2 tool through virtual box. Every time I run the virtual box the host system is getting restarted.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello Mounika, do you have any logs of the host system?

Comment: If you are referring to the vbox logs, then I have them

Answer (score 0):

You may firstly check for new updates on help menu. If still restarts; reinstall the program. Did you install x32 or x64 version for your computer which may x32 or x64?